# Save for azure Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, backup, database-backups

For a project of Web site I created a database on Azure. However I would want to know how is managed the backup and how to import or to export them.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This site is for coding and getting help on some posted code + traces. Please use StackExchange for general questions ans discussions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want import export beckups within azure check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups).

If you want to backup to your computer. One of possible options:

1. Connect to azure DB with your SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).
2. Find your Db left click -> `Tasks` -> `Export Data-tier application...`

This will allow you to get `.bacpac` file of your db. Now you're able to restore in to your local DB server like this:

1. Connect to local DB server
2. Left click on `Databases` folder -> `Import Data-tier application...`

**Note that there are scenarios when that won't help you**, becouse Azure SQL and stand alone SQL slightly different and some object doesn't exists in stand alone version. In this case you should use export/import and don't chose theese objects.

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL Database provides automated backups that have a retention period from 7 to 35 days depending of the edition of the database. However, you cannot export those automated backups. Learn more about automated backups [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups).

Azure SQL Database offers also long term retention backups as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-retention) but you cannot access or download them.

What you can do is to export your database from Azure SQL Database to Azure Blob storage account as a bacpac and then download it to your on-premise computer. You can export the database using the portal but you can also use the SqlPackage.exe utility as shown below.

```
SqlPackage.exe /a:Export /tf:testExport.bacpac /scs:"Data Source=apptestserver.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=MyDB;" /ua:True /tid:"apptest.onmicrosoft.com"
```

You can also use SQL Server Management Studio to export a database. Learn more about exporting a database [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export).

You can restore a bacpac to an Azure SQL database by importing it. You can use the portal, PowerShell but you can also use SqlPackage.exe utility as shown below:

```
SqlPackage.exe /a:import /tcs:"Data Source=mynewserver20170403.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=myMigratedDatabase;User Id=ServerAdmin;Password=<change_to_your_password>" /sf:AdventureWorks2008R2.bacpac /p:DatabaseEdition=Premium /p:DatabaseServiceObjective=P6
```

You can learn more about importing a bacpac [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import).

Comment: great and full answer

Comment: Thank you for your comments Teo.